# MaxListenersExceededWarning error when trying to download app with shoutem pull-app

Tags: shoutem

Hi I am trying to download an app built with the shoutem builder. 
I am using the command: `shoutem pull-app <app-id>`.

And I am getting this error:

```
Pulling the app `Small business app`...
Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email Enter your Shoutem credentials (obtained at https://builder.shoutem.com):
? Email (node:33417) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 keypress listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:33417) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:33417) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:33417) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:33417) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:33417) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Software versions:

- node: v7.9.0
- npm: 4.5.0
- shoutem: 0.8.137

Any idea what's is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try logging out, then logging in, and then running shoutem pull-app?

1. shoutem logout
2. shoutem login
3. shoutem pull-app

Comment: Can you try again? I think service might have been temporarily unavailable.

Comment: These errors happen because for some reason you're not logged in. The script tries to log you in for every extension you're pulling. Shoutem login returns no error? What does shoutem show command give you?

Comment: I logged out, logged in, did the pull and nothing.